# Adding to a float or double

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add 0.01 to my label every time I press the button but when I do so it outputs: 0.010000 instead of 0.01?

Here is my code:

//.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double userPoints;
```

//.m

```
- (IBAction)myButton 
{
self.userPoints = self.userPoints + 0.01;
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", self.userPoints];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell your float to only go out two decimal places by using %.2, like so:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf", self.userPoints];
```

Comment: I'm glad to help, that tends to throw off a lot of new programmers! :)

Answer (score 4):

While using C style format strings will work, if this is a user facing control it's likely better for a more localizable solution.

Take a look at NSNumberFormatter.  Something like this should work:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits: 2];
self.myLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: @(self.userPoints)];
```

(saving the formatter as a member would be more efficient too...)